# Is it possible to create a full SOAP Envelop message using jaxb2?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws, jaxb2

I am working on Spring-WS. I need to send an SOAP Envelop message to some JMS Queue as soon as  a request comes. I am using JAXB for marshaling. Is it possible to create full SOAP Envelop message using JAXB2? Also I need to use 2 XSDs, one XSD for SOAP Header part and another for SOAP Body.

Let me know if its possible with JAXB2 or any other technology should be used. A sample code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the job of JAX-B. The full soap envelope is the job of a frontend, like JAX-WS.

You can do this with Apache CXF. it has a JMS binding, it will send SOAP-over-JMS for you